# ¿Porque no respeta mi condición en el ciclo while?

Tags: java, android

Lo que pasa es que quiero meter un switch dentro de mi ciclo while, pero al momento que se ejecuta su condicion no me respeta lo que le pido.

```
while (contadorS<arrOperador.length) {

            switch (arrOperador[contadorS]) {
                case "+":
                    if (i==0) {
                        resultado=numero+numero2;
                    }else {
                        resultado=resultado+numero2;
                    }
                    break;
                case "-":
                    if (i==0) {

                        resultado=numero-numero2;
                    }else {
                        resultado=resultado-numero2;
                    }
                    break;
                case "*":
                    if (i==0) {

                        resultado=numero*numero2;
                    }else {
                        resultado=resultado*numero2;
                    }
                    break;
                case "/":
                    if (i==0) {

                        resultado=numero/numero2;
                    }else {
                        resultado=resultado/numero2;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            contadorS++;

}
```

Cuando mi variable es superior a la longitud de mi arreglo que contabiliza, sigue entrando a mi switch y por ende cuando llega a ejecutarlo me dice que el contadorS es mas grande que los indices que contiene mi arreglo y pues es porque no sale cuando se lo pido. ¿Podría ser algo de la cache de android studio?.

También lo intente hacer con el ciclo for, pero de igual forma no me sacaba cuando la condición no se cumplía, inclusive puse la siguiente condición estática `10<arrOperador.length` y tomando en cuenta que el arreglo es de indice 0 e indice 1 es improbable que eso fuese true.

El error lo marca en esta linea:

```
switch (arrOperador[contadorS])
```

Comment: ¿Cuando el programa intenta entrar al `switch` antes de salir el error, qué valores muestra `contadorS` y `arrOperador.length`?

Comment: @Lixus  el contador muestra un valor de 2 y el array muestra una longitud de 2 pero iniciando de cero, lo cual llegaría a uno y es ahí cuando truena porque yo le asigno un indice 2. Pero con la condición no debería entrar cuando el contador fuese 2

Comment: @JorgeSys pues no deberia entarar despues de que se cumpliera y no ahi no marca error ni deberia marcarlo. Lo marca en este punto.  switch (arrOperador[contadorS])

Comment: No hay más código antes del switch que afecte el valor de `contadorS`?

Comment: Ejecuté tu código en una aplicación standalone con un main y no tuve problemas, ¿Como tienes declarada tu variable contadorS? ¿Hay más código en donde  utilices la variable contadorS como bien te pregunta @Lixus ?

Comment: @David es importante agregues que tipo de error es el que obtienes, en realidad tu código no es incorrecto solo la inicialización de contadorS, siempre debe ser 0  amtes del while :)

Comment: Cuando probé el código al principio me daba un error de Array out of bounds... @Jorgesys , pero ahora mismo no recuerdo si había algún otro error más en la comparación del `while`  o era sólo que las variables no estaban declaradas. El hecho es que he intentado reproducir el error y no puedo hacerlo :). Bueno, lo encontré dándole a Ctrl+Z. Él tenía el `while` así muy al principio: **`while (contadorS<arrOperador.length) {`** el error estaba ahí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad tu código es correcto, el problema es que antes de realizar el `while`, debes inicializar siempre la variable `contadorS` :

```
int contadorS = 0;
```

y la variable `arrOperador`  debe ser un array de Strings conteniendo los operadores deseados,  por ejemplo:

```
 String[] arrOperador = {"+","-","*", "/", "+"};
```

Tambien cabe recalcar que el si el arreglo esta inicializado de la siguiente forma:

```
String arreglo[]= new String[100];
```

Aunque no se llenen 90 indices los tomara como la longitud de los 100 y eso causaria problema

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código de esta forma y me funciona.

Es posible que tengas problemas con alguna de tus variables.

```
        String[] arrOperador = {"+", "-", "*","/"};
        int contadorS = 0;
        int resultado=0;
        int numero=5;
        int numero2=4;
        int i=0;
        while (contadorS<arrOperador.length) {
            switch (arrOperador[contadorS]) {
                case "+":
                    if (i==0) {
                        resultado=numero+numero2;
                    }else {
                        resultado=resultado+numero2;
                    }
                    System.out.println("+ resultado: "+resultado);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    if (i==0) {

                        resultado=numero-numero2;
                    }else {
                        resultado=resultado-numero2;
                    }
                    System.out.println("- resultado: "+resultado);

                    break;
                case "*":
                    if (i==0) {

                        resultado=numero*numero2;
                    }else {
                        resultado=resultado*numero2;
                    }
                    System.out.println("* resultado: "+resultado);

                    break;
                case "/":
                    if (i==0) {

                        resultado=numero/numero2;
                    }else {
                        resultado=resultado/numero2;
                    }
                    System.out.println("/ resultado: "+resultado);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            contadorS++;

}
```

### En la salida:

```
+ resultado: 9
- resultado: 1
* resultado: 20
/ resultado: 1
```